# How to execute a sound when an object goes through another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, transparency

Hey StackOverflow community, I am making my very first game and I've run into a problem. The game is about a ball dodging obstacles in order to reach the end of a level. So my issue is that I want to implement a "Woosh" sound whenever the ball passes an obstacle. I have created an invisible object which is supposed to execute the "Woosh" sound whenever the ball passes the invisible object.

These are the settings on the "invisible" object: 
[image]

If you look at the image you can see that there is a "Woosh" script which contains these lines of code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Woosh : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Woosh");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to make the invisible object play the "Woosh" audio whenever it collides with the Player. However, when I try it out in game, the audio never gets played when I pass the invisible object.

For your information, I do have an audio manager, which contains all my sounds that I have implemented so far. It can be seen here:

[image]

Note: All the other sounds work, but not the "Woosh" sound.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
E.W

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `OnCollisionEnter` method gets called, and that the tag is equal to "Player"? Do you know if `FindObjectOfType` actually returns a value?

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that your "Woosh" sound will play? If you replace one of your other sound calls with "Woosh", does it play? What you have to do in situations like this is check everything that leads up to the sound being played. Don't just automatically assume that the sound or its settings is the problem.

Comment: Hey Jim, sorry I was gone for a while. So I tried replacing the "Woosh" sound in the Audio Manager with another sound, and none of the sounds worked. Also, could you explain what you mean in your first comment? I'm new to Unity that's why. For the time being I'll be looking for a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Jim I think you might have found the answer to my problem, but I still haven't quite figured it out yet.. so basically I changed "void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)" to "(void OnCollisionEnter(Woosh collisionInfo)". Hopefully that is a step in the right direction? Anyways, the part "collisionInfo.collider" in the script to the right has been underlined with a red color:
 "if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player")

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on `OnCollisionEnter`, or make a message pop up, or *anything* that would prove to you that the method is being called? Did you make sure that the `if` statement is evaluating to `true`, and that the code is actually calling `FindObjectOfType`? You can't just assume that the problem is with the "Woosh" sound. You can verify that the "Woosh" sound works by replacing a call to play "ShatterSmall", for example, with "Woosh". If the sound plays, then you know it works and that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: So I made sure that the 'Woosh' sound worked by putting it on another audios location. So there is something wrong with either the script or a small step I missed. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Comments aren't sufficient.

What I'm trying to tell you is that you can't just automatically assume that the problem is with the "Woosh" sound. That's just one of the things that can go wrong. You have this code:

```
public class Woosh : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Woosh");
        }
    }
}
```

Your expectation is that when `OnCollisionEnter` is called, the "Woosh" sound will be played. You say the sound isn't playing, so you have to figure out what's wrong. This is what I would check:

1. Can you make the "Woosh" sound play somewhere else? You should be able to add code to your program to make the "Woosh" sound play. Maybe replace code that plays "ShatterSmall" with "Woosh". If the sound doesn't play there, then there's probably something wrong with the "Woosh" sound, and you need to fix it. If the sound *does* play there, then there's some other problem.
2. If "Woosh" plays in other places, but not in this code, then you have to check to see if the code is even being executed. If you're running this code in your debugger, put a breakpoint on the `OnCollisionEnter` method to see if it gets called. If it doesn't get called, then the problem is somewhere else. If you don't have a debugger, then you can output some kind of message like "Hey, I got here!" to tell you that the `OnCollisionEnter` function actually was called.
3. If you're getting to `OnCollisionEnter`, then you need to check to see if `collisionInfo.collider.tag` does indeed contain the value "Player". Again, use some kind of output function to tell you what is in that variable.
4. If `collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player"`, then check to see if the call to `FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>` returns the expected value.

You can break up your code:

```
var mgr = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();
if (mgr == null)
{
    // some error here. Maybe throw an exception.
}
else
{
    // Make sure (somehow) that it's really the object you wanted
}
mgr.Play("Woosh");
```

5. If the above tells you that you're getting the right object, then perhaps there's a problem playing the sound. Does `Play` throw any exceptions?

The point I'm trying to make here is that debugging involves questioning all of your assumptions, and doing tests to see where things are failing. This is best done with a debugger, because it lets you move through your code step-by-step to see *exactly* what's happening.

If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It will save you *days* of debugging.

Comment: This is really handy, I'll be sure to follow these steps whenever I run into a problem. Thanks a lot Jim Mischel!

Answer (score 0):

It won't be making the sound because your collider is a trigger not a collision, so if you disable that box of Is Trigger, the sound will play when you collide with it.

If you want to pass through the collider like a trigger you need to use this functions.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {}
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {}
```

EDIT:
Also using FindObjectOfType is an expensive function, just make the Audio Manager a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Hey jour, when I disabled the box "Is trigger" the sound did indeed play! However, the obstacle doesnt allow the player to pass through it. Do you mean I am supposed to use the functions you wrote above in order for the player to be able to go through the object? Thanks in advance, E.W

Comment: Exactly, you need to keep the object as a Trigger to pass through it, and have the function to be a OnTrigger instead of OnCollision.